# How to change button size?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have button in my `ViewController` in storyboard. And I add some constraints to my button in storyboard. I want to change button size in code. But my code doesn’t work. How to fix it?

```
@IBOutlet var font: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    font = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(50), height: CGFloat(20)))
}
```

Comment: where is the button outlet and you other code for button??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect you button from code with Interface Builder and set up constraints, you can change the size of button by changing constraints' constant.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var heightConstaint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func foo() {
        heightConstaint.constant = 50.0
        view.setNeedsLayout()
    }
  }
```

If you don't use constraints, you can just change frame of view.

`button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 100)`

Answer (score 0):

You can update the button constraints, update from the code, or from the storyboard to take out the constraints, modify it

Answer (score 0):

First you create button constraints Outlet . then modify the constraints like this:

```
 self.buttonWidthConstaint.constant = 100.0
```